# Прочитать файл c кириллицей и отобразить на html странице

Tags: javascript, html, кодировка

Пытаюсь прочитать текст из файла и отобразить на html странице `fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8")`.
Я знаю кодировку файла и могу изменить ее, если нужно. Пробовал менять кодировку самого файла(Не кодировку в NodeJs): `cp65001 (UTF-8)`, `cp1251 (ANSI - кириллица)`, `cp866 (OEM - русская)`, `28595 (ISO 8859-5 кириллица)`, но всегда вместо нормального текста на странице и в консоли получался набор нечитаемых символов.
Вопрос не дубликат "Программное определение кодировки текстового файла из заданного списка", вопрос состоит не в определении кодировки файла, а в правильном отображении в html и в консоли.

Comment: Надо узнать, в какой кодировке у вас файл. А потом указать эту кодировку при открытии. Может, у вас там вообще DOS кодировка))

Comment: Вообще-то нода ничего кроме utf-8 не умеет.

Comment: Поищите какой-нибудь пакет типа iconv

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Я же указал, что пробовал разные кодировки файла, в том числе и UTF-8

Comment: Вот именно, вы пробуете разные кодировки. Кодировок на свете больше 1000. Поэтому надо узнать, какая кодировка у файла! А потом ее уже использовать. Можно спросить у [google](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enUZ780UZ780&ei=3A2aW5C0DMKisAHxmoa4Ag&q=file+encoding+online&oq=file+encoding+on)'а, как узнать кодировку файла.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Я и так знаю, какая у файла кодировка, я сохраняю файл в нужной, если нужно в UTF-8, если нужно в другой, но у меня в любой кодировке (В том числе UTF-8) получается не кириллица, а набор нечитаемых символов. Я ставлю кодировку файла на UTF-8, в файле, который запускаю через NodeJs пишу `fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8")`, но в итоге получается `Ð˜ÑÐºÐ°Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð² Google`

Comment: Прикрепите ваш файл в кодировке `utf-8` к вопросу. Надо посмотреть, какая там реальная кодировка.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Возможно вы не понимаете, но я прекрасно знаю, какая кодировка у файла, как это узнать и т.д. Моя проблема заключается в коде, я не знаю, как в NodeJs сделать страницу сайта с нормальным, читаемым кириллическим текстом, загруженным из файла

Comment: Окей, если знаете, тогда делайте. Удачи!

Comment: Node.js не имеет отношения к вашему вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Для загрузки файла нужно, чтобы он был в кодировке UTF-8.

P.S. Для корректного отображения текста в UTF-8 нужно:

1. В среде разработки указать UTF-8, как стандартную кодировку:

   - В eclipse - Window/Preferences/General/Workspace Text file encoding/Other/UTF-8
2. В `<head>` html файла должно быть прописано `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`